# Cannot enable auto layout in storyboard

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I have a project that I created before auto layout came out.  My projects has two storyboards - a main one (quite complex, 10+ screens) and a secondary one (just a few screens).  I'm trying to enable auto layout for my project, but am unable to do so for the main storyboard.

I'm accessing the file inspector, then checking the "Use Autolayout" checkbox in the Interface Builder Document panel.  While this worked fine for the secondary storyboard, when I click the checkbox for the main one I'm getting the beachball for a few seconds (and the previously empty checkbox turns to a "-"), then a lock HUD is displayed and the checkbox returned to the unchecked state.  I couldn't find any documentation about this - what does the lock refer to?  I do have quite a few locked views in my screens, am I supposed to unlock them before converting the storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

For me helped "Reset Locking Controls" below "Use Autolayout" checkbox. Than conversion worked !